# Bootstrap glyphicon appended with LESS, no html touching

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less, glyphicons

I wonder if there's a possibility to append a Bootstrap glyphicon without touching HTML and use it as a LESS mixin like so:

```
a {
 .glyphicon;
 .glyphicon-envelope;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: looks quite doable so you want all the a (links) to have the envelope :before? That's odd. Remember this is a pseudo element, so wouldn't it be .selector a:before {.gyphicon;.glyphicon-envelope;} ?

Comment: when you mixin `.glyphicon-envelope` it already set the pseudo class, you do have to set that explicitly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can:

**less**

```
@import "variables.less";
@import (reference) "glyphicons.less";

a {
 .glyphicon;
 .glyphicon-envelope;
}
```

will compile into the following CSS:

```
a {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
a:before {
  content: "\2709";
}
```

Notice that you should not use the reference keyword with the @import if you want to use the CSS without the complete Bootstrap CSS or add the font definition to your Less code:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('@{icon-font-path}@{icon-font-name}.eot');
  src: url('@{icon-font-path}@{icon-font-name}.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('@{icon-font-path}@{icon-font-name}.woff') format('woff'),
       url('@{icon-font-path}@{icon-font-name}.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('@{icon-font-path}@{icon-font-name}.svg#@{icon-font-svg-id}') format('svg');
}
```

Also consider the [extend feature](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature) of Less:

**less**

```
@import "variables.less";
@import (reference) "glyphicons.less";

a {
 &:extend(.glyphicon);
 &:extend(.glyphicon-envelope all);
}
```

Comment: It seems this doesn't work with input fields (e.g. extending .searchbox with glyphicon-search)